# Another invert char array in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, mifare

That code will run on a payment device (POS). I have to use legacy C (not C# or C++) for that purpose.

I am trying to prepare a simple Mifare card read/write software data. Below document is my reference and I am trying to achieve what is on page 9, 8.6.2.1 Value blocks explains.
http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf

I just know very basics of C. All my searches in The Internet have failed. According to document:

1- There is integer variable with value of `1234567`.

2- There is `char array[4]` which should have hex of above value which is `0x0012D687`

3- I am supposed to invert that char array[4] and reach value of `0xFFED2978`

I need to do some other things but I have stuck in number 3 above. What I have tried lastly is

```
int value = 1234567;
char valuebuffer[4];
char invertbuffer[4];

sprintf(valuebuffer, "%04x", value);  
for(i = 0;  i < sizeof(valuebuffer);  i++ )
{   
    invertbuffer[i] ^= valuebuffer[i];  
}
```

When I print, I read some other value in `invertbuffer` and not `0xFFED2978`

Comment: `^ is bitwise XOR, are you looking for `~` (bitwise NOT)? Also `sprintf` writes the number as text.

Comment: ... and in the `sprintf` case the buffer will overflow.

Comment: `sprintf(valuebuffer, "%04x", 1234567)` needs a buffer size of _at least_ 7 to store _string_ `"12D687"`.

Comment: You need to invert the `value`, not it's string representation `valuebuffer`.

Comment: Can you just do `printf("%x", ~((unsigned)value));` ?

Comment: As I indicated, I just know very basics of C and that leads me to a lot of errors. Thank you all for all your explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. You can do the binary inversion on the `int` variable rather than messing around with individual bytes.

```
int value = 1234567;
int inverted= ~ value;

printf("%x\n",value);
printf("%x\n",inverted);
```

gives you output of

> 12d687
>
> ffed2978

Comment: If you perform bitwise operations on `signed` integer types, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @mlp I'm sure the OP has their reasons for using signed ints

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must use the types from stdint.h and not `char`, because the latter has implementation-defined signedness and is therefore overall unsuitable for holding raw binary data.

With that sorted, you can use a union for maximum flexibility:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
  uint32_t u32;
  uint8_t  u8 [4];
} uint32_union_t;

int main (void)
{
  uint32_union_t x;
  x.u32 = 1234567;

  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    printf("%X ", x.u8[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  x.u32 = ~x.u32;

  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    printf("%X ", x.u8[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Notably, the access order of the u8 is endianess dependent. This might be handy when dealing with something like RFID, which doesn't necessarily have the same network endianess as your MCU.

Comment: Not _must_ but _should_ use the types from `<stdint.h>`. `unsigned char` is perfectly usable as a non-negative integer of at least 8 bits, and similarly `unsigned long` is a non-negative integer of at least 32 bits everywhere.